# Api response gives generic response

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-iam

I am trying to generate a oauth token for a service account on google. I am getting a generic response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I am not sure which field is invalid `https://cloud.google.com/iam/credentials/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/generateAccessToken`

I followed the steps in this url `https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Include your source code. An error mesage is not helpful without the source. Also, clearly show the headers and body of your HTTP request and the IAM policy for the service account that you are using. If you would like to understand how to create an access token from service account credentials, I wrote an article in Python: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/ . The difference between my acticle and the one you referenced is that I create short-lived credentials. Your article creates short-lived `delegated` credentials.

Comment: I got it working. The pattern for the name field was wrong. It has to be `projects/-/serviceAccounts/<service-account-name>`. It would be better if the error message was meaningful